# No strict inequalities in cvxpy problem but still get the error "Strict inequalities are not allowed"

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, cvxpy

I was using the CVXPY library in Python, trying to solve a particular optimization problem.

```
import cvxpy as cp
import numpy as np
from scipy.stats import norm

(...)

a = cp.Variable([10, 1])

obj = cp.Maximize(sum(norm.logcdf(A @ a, scale=sigma)))
constraints = [a >= np.zeros([10, 1]), a <= np.ones([10, 1])]

prob = cp.Problem(objective=obj, constraints=constraints)

prob.solve()
```

Here A is a particular numpy Matrix, and sigma is a particular scalar. When I try to solve the question, the package gives me the below error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "~\anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 3326, in run_code
    exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)
  File "<ipython-input-23-c554382c1c69>", line 19, in <module>
    obj = cp.Maximize(sum(norm.logcdf(A @ a, scale=sigma)))
  File "~\anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/scipy/stats/_distn_infrastructure.py", line 1848, in logcdf
    cond1 = self._open_support_mask(x, *args) & (scale > 0)
  File "~\anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/scipy/stats/_distn_infrastructure.py", line 901, in _open_support_mask
    return (a < x) & (x < b)
  File "~\anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/cvxpy/expressions/expression.py", line 597, in __gt__
    raise NotImplementedError("Strict inequalities are not allowed.")
NotImplementedError: Strict inequalities are not allowed.
```

But the problem itself contains no strict inequality... Seems like the SCIPY package has conflict with CVXPY, but have no idea how to resolve...

Comment: CVXPY expressions, such as the variable `a`, cannot be used in NumPy or SciPy functions. You must build your objective and constraint functions using the CVXPY atoms.

Comment: @AkshayAgrawal Thanks for your help. I understand the problem but not sure if CVXPY has an atom for the CDF function of standard normal distribution.

Comment: CVXPY does not have an atom for the CDF of a standard normal distribution.

Answer (score 1):

There is a `norm` in cvxpy. So please change as below code:

```
from scipy.stats import stats
obj = cp.Maximize(sum(stats.logcdf(A @ a, scale=sigma)))
```

[functions](https://www.cvxpy.org/tutorial/functions/index.html#scalar-functions)

Comment: Thanks for your help. I tried the `cp.norm.logcdf` function but found the `logcdf` was not available under cvxpy. Basically I was trying to call a CDF function of the normal distribution.

Comment: Because there is a `norm` in cp. Could you please change `from scipy.stats import norm` to something like: `from scipy.stats import stats`? and `obj = cp.Maximize(sum(stats.logcdf(A @ a, scale=sigma)))`

Comment: Hi Mahsa, I changed the code as you mentioned. It comes up with other error `AttributeError: module 'scipy.stats.stats' has no attribute 'logcdf'`.

Comment: When you have `from scipy.stats import stats` you just need to write `stats.logcdf`